# Constructor and property namespaces bringing up "URI is not registered" error

Tags: xml, spring, intellij-idea

[image: Namespace giving an error]

As you can see, I've declared a namespace for the constructor namespace, however it says the URI is not registered. I have a few ideas how to fix them, but I'm not sure how to implement them.

1. I could manually register the URI, however, I would need a matching .xsd file for that, and looking around, I can't find one for that specific namespace.
2. I tried ignoring the error and seeing if that would fix it, but when I did that the XML parser didn't recognize the elements (should have seen that coming)

Not sure what's going on here. Every single example I've found online has this exact line copied in order to make use of the c & p namespaces (this error also happens for the p namespace). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define this schema location in Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs → [External Schemas and DTDs﻿](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-languages-schemas-and-dtds.html#external_schemas_and_dtds) settings:

[image]

It may be a directory a XSD or DTD file in one of you library jars or file on the file system.